# Default Project Protection Level for SSIS in VS 2012

Tags: ssis

How do you set the Default Project Protection Level for SSIS in VS 2012?

I want it to be Encrypt Sensitive Data with Password but currently, new projects are set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.

Is there a registry setting or an option I can set for the IDE to create new projects with a protection level of EncryptSensitiveWithPassword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How do you set the default project protection level?

By default, in the Project Deployment Model, new projects and packages are created with `EncryptSensitiveDateWithUserKey`. Changing this protection level at the Project level will ensure that all new packages created are created using the appropriate Package Protection Level

### Is there a registry setting or an option I can set for the IDE to create new projects with a protection level of EncryptSensitiveWithPassword?

Not that I'm aware of. You could always turn on [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and see what it accesses when it creates a project and I salute that as a nerdy endeavor but is the amount of time you spend researching that going to offset the number of times you create new SSIS projects? Since your packages follow the project's level, I have not found it to be an unbearable burden and I like SSIS as you may be able to gather from my rep here.

### EncryptSensitiveDataWithPassword

Unless you have a really compelling reason for this one, I would advise against it. Unless you're the sole developer, it creates a "shared" key which defeats the purpose of securing sensitive data. "Three may keep a secret, if two of them are dead"

When you deploy to the server, the protection level for the project and the packages is going to be changed to Server protection level as it is, so I don't see much value in juggling passwords that only marginally secure something and get thrown away. Unasked for advice, I know, but I have seen too many people complicate their projects for little gain.

Comment: Thanks for the insight BillInKC.  My efforts are to support a team of 6 by developing a template that will support the conversions of 300+ DTS packages and 2005 ssis packages.  They have asked for password protection so the template dtsx has this level.  New projects will not and will force going through the process of modifying the projects when started (if the template is used).  I do see your point and will bring this up with my client - thanks for your time and insight.